# Script doesn't work on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a small discord bot in python. On windows it works perfectly fine, but when I try to run it on raspbain, it says invalid syntax (with the command "python3 Bot.py")
Here's the code:

```
import feedparser
from yaml import load, dump
from json import dumps as jdump
from requests import post
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
BASE_URL = "https://discordapp.com/api"


def get_from_summary(summary):
    root = ET.fromstring(f"<element>{summary}</element>")
    d = f"{root[1].text}\n\n{root[2].text}"
    i = root[0].attrib["src"]
    return (d, i)
```

The syntax is at `root = ET.fromstring(f"<element>{summary}</element>")` with the "

Comment: Hello. Could you paste the error output, please?

Comment: What is the `f"..."` notation? My Python 3.5 doesn’t recognize it.

Comment: please show the exact error.

Comment: @Boldewyn It comes with Python 3.6; see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code uses [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (the `f"<element>{summary}</element>"`), which were only introduced in Python 3.6, so you need to use at least that version of Python.